# Mkdir perl error: no such file

Tags: perl

I am trying to make a directory in the following code:

```
# reads in files from a corpus
    for my $corpusFile (glob("./Corpus/*.txt")) {

    # makes part of the name of the file the name for a directory
    my $file = substr ($corpusFile, 9, 6);
    my $outputFiles = "./Output/$file";
    mkdir $outputFiles unless -e $outputFiles or die "Cannot make file directory: $!";
```

However, I get the error: 
`Cannot make file directory: No such file or directory at perl/corpus.pl`

I don't really understand this error. Of course the directory doesn't exist - I'm trying to create it.

To explain my file structure a bit: I have a big folder that contains an "output" folder and a "perl" folder - my perl code is in the folder called "perl" and I'm trying to create a directory in "output." I am very new to perl, so I apologize if the answer here is obvious.

Comment: does `Output` exist? mkdir won't recursively create a structure for you.

Comment: If $file is directory, why is it called file? If $file is a dir then your test should be -d not -e. To recursively create dirs use File::Path.

Comment: Thank you for your help - Output does exist, though, and it's called file because it's not yet a directory. It made sense to me, but I'll admit I could have clearer variable names.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at how this expression:

```
mkdir $outputFiles 
    unless -e $outputFiles 
or die "Cannot make file directory: $!";
```

is parsed by Perl, the answer is apparent. You can see how this is parsed using (-p prints parentheses):

```
perl -MO=Deparse,-p \ 
     -e 'mkdir "foo" unless -e "foo" or die "Cannot create foo: $!"
```

produces:

```
(((-e 'foo') or die("Cannot create foo: $!")) or mkdir('foo'));
-e syntax OK
```

Now you should be able to see the issue, according to the above expression:

1) If directory `'foo'` does not exist, the program will die with the message `'Cannot create foo: No such file or directory'`

2) If directory `'foo'` does exist, the program will call `mkdir 'foo'`. This is pointless however, since it already exists.